# wxWidgets alignment problems

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to create with wxWidgets window in which to top listbox, its size changed when you change the window size. Below are three buttons which size does not change when window size changed. Distance between the buttons and listbox constantly, and does not change when you resize the window.

Answer (score 1):

You want a vertical `wx.BoxSizer` with proportion of `1` and `wx.EXPAND` flag. This sizer will have in it your listbox, added with proportion of `1` and `wx.EXPAND` flag. This sizer will also have in it a horizontal box sizer with the three buttons added. You want to do a `window.SetSizer(<your vertical sizer>)` to the "window" you mention (probably a `wx.Frame`).

Answer (score 0):

```
void SizerTest::CreateControls()
{    
////@begin SizerTest content construction
    SizerTest* itemFrame1 = this;

    wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    itemFrame1->SetSizer(itemBoxSizer2);

    wxArrayString itemListBox3Strings;
    wxListBox* itemListBox3 = new wxListBox( itemFrame1, ID_LISTBOX2, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, itemListBox3Strings, wxLB_SINGLE );
    itemBoxSizer2->Add(itemListBox3, 1, wxGROW|wxLEFT|wxRIGHT|wxTOP, 5);

    wxBoxSizer* itemBoxSizer4 = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    itemBoxSizer2->Add(itemBoxSizer4, 0, wxALIGN_LEFT, 0);

    wxButton* itemButton5 = new wxButton( itemFrame1, ID_BUTTON3, _("Button"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemBoxSizer4->Add(itemButton5, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

    wxButton* itemButton6 = new wxButton( itemFrame1, ID_BUTTON4, _("Button"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemBoxSizer4->Add(itemButton6, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

    wxButton* itemButton7 = new wxButton( itemFrame1, ID_BUTTON5, _("Button"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    itemBoxSizer4->Add(itemButton7, 0, wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wxALL, 5);

////@end SizerTest content construction
}
```

Should look like this: http://screencast.com/t/ZonUBhPZ7

Resized: http://screencast.com/t/zRDpDix7Yr